# How do i use property files having my application properties in WSO2 EI

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I wish to use property files in WSO2 ESB project.
I am using WSO EI 6.5 with Integration Profile.

To be more precise

```
<inboundEndpoint name="main-endpoint" onError="error-handler-flow" protocol="jms" sequence="main-flow" suspend="false" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <parameters>
        <parameter name="interval">500</parameter>
        <parameter name="sequential">true</parameter>
        <parameter name="coordination">true</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.jms.Destination">Main</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.jms.CacheLevel">3</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName">QueueConnectionFactory</parameter>
        <parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial">org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory</parameter>
        <parameter name="java.naming.provider.url">failover:(tcp://localhost:61616)?initialReconnectDelay=100&amp;maxReconnectDelay=5000</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.jms.SessionAcknowledgement">CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.jms.SessionTransacted">false</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType">queue</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.jms.ContentType">application/json</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.jms.SharedSubscription">false</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.jms.ResetConnectionOnPollingSuspension">false</parameter>
    </parameters>
</inboundEndpoint>
```

In the above Inbound Endpoint, I wish that the queue name (transport.jms.Destination) and broker URL (java.naming.provider.url) to be read from properties file which are maintained for each environment (qa, staging, production). The property files themselves are not part of CAR application.

I imagine this could be done using registry, however I am not sure and I am unable to do this for quite some time now.

Please note that I wish to avoid writing any custom class or scripts to do this. I hope that WSO2 ESB has an available way of reading external property files. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The local registry acts as a memory registry where you can store static content as a key-value pair, where the value could be a static entry such as a text string, XML code, or a URL. This is useful for the type of static content often found in XSLT files, WSDL files, URLs, etc. Local entries can be referenced from mediators in the ESB profile mediation flows and resolved at runtime.

Please refer [1]

The  element is used to declare registry entries that are local to the the ESB profile instance as shown below:

```
<localEntry key="string" src="url">text | xml</localEntry>
```

These entries are top-level entries and are globally visible within the entire system. Values of these entries can be retrieved via the extension XPath function

```
synapse:get-property(prop-name)
```

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/Working+with+Local+Registry+Entries